# How to customize ASP .NET Web API JWT token response?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I am using Asp.net Webform project with Web API. I configured JWT token-based authentication and now I want to customize the authentication response

Here are my configurations,

1. Startup.cs

   ```
   public class Startup
   {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            ConfigureOAuth(app);

            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

            WebApiConfig.Register(config);

        }

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            String apiHttpOnly = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AllowInsecureHttp"];
            String tokenTimeSpan = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tokenTimeSpanFromMinutes"];

            bool allowInsecureHttp = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(apiHttpOnly) ? 
                                     Convert.ToBoolean(apiHttpOnly) : false;
            int accessTokenExpireTimeSpan = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenTimeSpan) ? 
                                     Convert.ToInt32(tokenTimeSpan) : 60;

            var authProvider = new AuthorizationServiceProvider();
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                //For Dev enviroment only (on production should be AllowInsecureHttp = false)
                AllowInsecureHttp = allowInsecureHttp,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/authenticate"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(accessTokenExpireTimeSpan),
                Provider = authProvider
            };

            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);

        }
   }
   ```
2. AuthorizationServiceProvider

   ```
    public class AuthorizationServiceProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            context.Validated();
            return base.ValidateClientAuthentication(context);
        }

        public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);

            if (Membership.ValidateUser(context.UserName, context.Password))
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", context.UserName));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "admin admin"));
                context.Validated(identity);
            }
            else
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Provide username and password is incorrect.");

            }

            return base.GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(context);
        }
    }
   ```

When I call the API with the right credentials, it returns like

```
{
    "access_token": "uEwmXl6N0mJXVUZesxA_2tG5lIuZUIUDaxtjAl0QGE6j2-J7n4c63zboOUClGjRQf1IDY9-nBgyq0HP5WR7MMxTYoHGIyiHIbcKu9AYwhECCGaVBCxY2Ounhit4N1pYK1vV6uX6AcoA-a0xhytF8Jz27D77ZvCLi3PuUQDEXSp0pkGG796wu1fRZCaRsCB-kLoa-_V7KJaGGhhoybN_c0GNOBhhwmGpx6Js26-Vx-lmWpfsPUE1aKrJfx-oMcyE5x7CooAlx4vA6iZhnNfmYdRejRKoKKnObyuAsym7mVdZY3bpv",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 5183999
}
```

I want to customize the response by adding some extra attributes like,

```
{
    "access_token": "uEwmXl6N0mJXVUZesxA_2tG5lIuZUIUDaxtjAl0QGE6j2-J7n4c63zboOUClGjRQf1IDY9-nBgyq0HP5WR7MMxTYoHGIyiHIbcKu9AYwhECCGaVBCxY2Ounhit4N1pYK1vV6uX6AcoA-a0xhytF8Jz27D77ZvCLi3PuUQDEXSp0pkGG796wu1fRZCaRsCB-kLoa-_V7KJaGGhhoybN_c0GNOBhhwmGpx6Js26-Vx-lmWpfsPUE1aKrJfx-oMcyE5x7CooAlx4vA6iZhnNfmYdRejRKoKKnObyuAsym7mVdZY3bpv",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 5183999,
    "attribute1" : "abc",
    "attribute2" : "ert"
}
```

Anyone have an idea to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I investigate the problem and find out the solution. I posted it here, maybe it may help someone.

1. Add **AuthenticationProperties**

   ```
   var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
   {
       {
            "attribute1" , "abc"
       },
       {
            "attribute2" , "ert"
       }
   });
   ```
2. Then create Ticket using **AuthenticationTicket**

   ```
   var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
   ```
3. Add ticket to the **context**

   ```
   context.Validated(ticket);
   ```
4. Then implement the override method **TokenEndpoint**

   ```
    public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
        {
            context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
        }
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
   ```

Finally **AuthorizationServiceProvider** class be like,

```
public class AuthorizationServiceProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
        return base.ValidateClientAuthentication(context);
    }

    public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.UserName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Password))
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_request", "No username or password are provided.");
        }
        else if (Membership.ValidateUser(context.UserName, context.Password))
        {
            
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));

            /*
             * All custom response props are define here.
             * --------usage----------
             * use as dictionary
             * */
            var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                //{
                //    "test" , "val"
                //}
            });

            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);


            context.Validated(ticket);
        }
        else
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Provide username and password is incorrect.");

        }

        return base.GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(context);
    }

    public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
        {
            context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
        }
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

For more info - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26369622/8403632

Sample Example - https://github.com/Leftyx/OwinWebApiBearerToken